# How is Magician Humphrey a magician?

Tags: piers-anthony, character-development, xanth

I've read the first 13 or so Xanth novels. From what I can see, Magician Humphrey doesn't really know the answer to questions. He always uses other means to get the answer, be it a demon, a book he has, some coersion from others, etc.

How is he considered to have magician status if he never actually comes up with the answers on his own?

If his talent is to be able to find a means to find the answer, how is that a Magician level gift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Humphrey's talent is actually knowing *how and where* to find the answers to questions, rather than actual omniscience.  I read roughly as far into the series as you did, but it appears that [Humfrey's past and powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magicians_of_Xanth#Humfrey) were addressed in more detail later on in the series:

> In Heaven Cent, it is implied that Humfrey's actual magical talent may
>   be no more than that of locating other magic that may be of use to
>   him. Though probably not magical talents, he does have extreme
>   curiosity and a (usually) very good memory, which through the course
>   of his life led him to become a master of information, as he recounted
>   in Question Quest. *Further, he recounted that he had believed that his
>   native magical talents were not magician-class*, and that he attended
>   Demon University and gained a degree in magic, so that he could
>   deserve the Magician appellation by which he had already become known.

In some ways, it is really not that much different from how Bink's talent employs intermediaries, rather than simply causing magic against him to "fizzle".

Comment: That beggs the question of where Demon University is, lol.